# Unable to read file even though in same group

Tags: linux, permissions, administration

I created new symbolic link to one file(located in another user home directory) for the user. But unable to read even though the user in same group and the file permissions are 755.

```
[lmurugan@localhost ~]$ ls -lrt
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root       root       34 Feb 16 16:36 3000.log -> /home/dkanagaraj/.forever/f3-w.log
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 dkanagaraj dkanagaraj 34 Feb 16 16:38 3030.log -> /home/dkanagaraj/.forever/z_lZ.log
[lmurugan@localhost ~]$ less 3030.log
3030.log: Permission denied


[lmurugan@localhost ~]$ ls -lrt
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root       root       34 Feb 16 16:36 3000.log -> /home/dkanagaraj/.forever/f3-w.log
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 dkanagaraj dkanagaraj 34 Feb 16 16:38 3030.log -> /home/dkanagaraj/.forever/z_lZ.log

[lmurugan@localhost ~]$ id
uid=1006(lmurugan) gid=1000(dkanagaraj) groups=1000(dkanagaraj)

[lmurugan@localhost ~]$ id dkanagaraj
uid=1000(dkanagaraj) gid=1000(dkanagaraj) groups=1000(dkanagaraj),10(wheel)

[dkanagaraj@localhost .forever]$ ls -lrt /home/dkanagaraj/.forever/f3-w.log
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 dkanagaraj dkanagaraj 425361 Feb 16 16:46 /home/dkanagaraj/.forever/f3-w.log

[dkanagaraj@localhost .forever]$ ls -lrt /home/dkanagaraj/.forever/z_lZ.log
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 dkanagaraj dkanagaraj 570027 Feb 16 16:46 /home/dkanagaraj/.forever/z_lZ.log
```

Comment: what are the permissions for the `/home/dkanagaraj` directory ? Can you post the output of `ls -ld /home/dkanagaraj` command ?

Comment: Also `/home/dkanagaraj/.forever`. And the dot at the end of permissions indicates SELinux is installed; check if it's active with `getenforce` and what 'context' the files have with `ls -Z`.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the output of the commands.

First, "3030.log" is a link

```
[lmurugan@localhost ~]$ ls -lrt 
total 0 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root       root       34 Feb 16 16:36 3000.log -> /home/dkanagaraj/.forever/f3-w.log
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 dkanagaraj dkanagaraj 34 Feb 16 16:38 3030.log -> /home/dkanagaraj/.forever/z_lZ.log
```

the "l" in the first position shows this as does the "-> /home/dkanagaraj/.forever/z_lZ.log"

so show the permissions of the file you are linked to as well as permissions of the parent directories , dkanagaraj and .forever

```
ls -l /home/dkanagaraj/.forever/z_lZ.log
```

See http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php for a discussion of both file and directory permissions.

Comment: To add to this, the reason you see the permissions `lrwxrwxrwx` is because those are the permissions on the symbolic link. All symbolic links have full permissions by default, because they only point you to a file/directory, whose permissions will still be enforced.

Comment: `ls -l` of the targets is already in the question. And shows `g=r-x` which should (normally) give read access.

Comment: depends on the permissions of the parent directories as well. Could also be selinux.

Answer (score -1):

bodhi.zazen's answer is right, but I'd like to answer it a little differently: permissions attach to the inode, and the symbolic link and its target have each their own inode.  Consider *foo* and *issues*, below:

```
$ ls -l foo issues
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jklowden jklowden    6 Feb 18 16:46 foo -> issues
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jklowden jklowden 2380 Jan 29 14:02 issues

$ stat foo
  File: ‘foo’ -> ‘issues’
  Size: 6               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 811h/2065d      Inode: 11406493    Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/jklowden)   Gid: ( 1000/jklowden)
Access: 2016-02-18 16:46:52.224805576 -0500
Modify: 2016-02-18 16:46:40.905398163 -0500
Change: 2016-02-18 16:46:40.905398163 -0500
 Birth: -

$ stat issues 
  File: ‘issues’
  Size: 2380            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 811h/2065d      Inode: 11405468    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/jklowden)   Gid: ( 1000/jklowden)
Access: 2016-01-29 14:05:26.122808636 -0500
Modify: 2016-01-29 14:02:52.106866058 -0500
Change: 2016-01-29 14:02:52.106866058 -0500
 Birth: -
```

Usually the permissions on a file control what you can do with it, but as it happens on most systems the permissions on a symbolic link file control nothing.  (You can **chmod 0 foo**, and still **ln -sf foo bar** works.)  Here, the permissions on inode 11405468 are the ones that count.

[What follows is corrected.  Thanks to dave_thompson_085 for his clarifying comment.]

In your example, the real file (not the symlink) is of course `f3-w.log`.  Since it's owned by your group, dkanagaraj, and has group read privileges, you'd expect to be able to read its contents, regardless of what if any symlink you used.

Rights to read the file are *also* controlled by the path to it.  *When accessing a file, execute permission is required on all of the directories listed in the pathname.* ([Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/), section 15.4.3, page 297).  Because the symlink uses an absolute pathname to its target, the **dkanagaraj** group needs *execute* permission on each pathname component: `/`, `home`, `dkanagaraj`, and `.forever`. The path-permission constraint applies to any file, including the symlink itself, but I think you have that covered.

Comment: OP is using the link whose target is `z_lZ.log`; both targets are owned by `dkanagaraj` while OPs userid is `lmurugan` but *group* is `dkanagaraj`. And *has* `g=r-x` but still can't be read.